# Nodejs x MySQL2 INSERT a variable

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql2, node-mysql2

Good day!
Im having a little problem with my nodeJS x MySQL Database.
I connected them together, working fine, im just struggling to insert data, especially inserting a variable such as a project title.
Example:
`var titleVariable = "Project1"; INSERT INTO projects (Title) VALUES (titleVariable);`
obviously I know that code isnt working like this, but I guess that shows the best whats my problem. Im looking forward for some helpful answers :-) Thank you all already!

Comment: use `.query('INSERT INTO projects (Title) VALUES (?)', [titleVariable])` its all well documented https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#performing-queries

Comment: thsnls a lot @LawrenceCherone, saved my day :)